# Developing/using a custom Resource Plugin in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

We have used Zend_Log, which is configured in application.ini differently for different circumstances. We initialize it/get it in the bootstrap and store it in the registry:

```
$r = $this->getPluginResource('log');
$logger = $r->getLog();
```

But we've subclassed Zend_Log (say, Our_Log) to add customized features, and want to get it the same way. So then we have to make a new Resource Plugin. That seems quite easy - just copy Application/Resource/Log.php, rename the file to Ourlog.php, rename the class to class Zend_Application_Resource_Ourlog. For now, let's not worry about "Our_Log", the class -- just use the new Resource Plugin to get a Zend_Log, to reduce the variables.

So then, our new code in the bootstrap is:

```
$r = $this->getPluginResource('ourlog');
$logger = $r->getLog();
```

but of course this doesn't work, error applying method to non-object "r".  According to the documentation,

> "As long as you register the prefix path for this resource plugin, you
>   can then use it in your application."

but how do you register a prefix path? That would have been helpful. But that shouldn't matter, I used the same prefix path as the default, and I know the file is being read because I "require" it.

Anyway, any guidance on what simple step I'm missing would be greatly appreciated.

---

Thanks for the pointers -- so close, so close (I think). I thought I was getting it...

Okay, so I renamed the class Xyz_Resource_Xyzlog, I put it in  `library/Xyz/Resource/Xyzlog.php`

Then, because I don't love ini files, in the bootstrap I put:

```
$loader=$this->getPluginLoader();
$loader->addPrefixPath('Xyz_Resource','Xyz/Resource/');
$r = $this->getPluginResource('xyzlog');
if (!is_object($r)) die ('Not an object!!');
```

Sudden Death. So, okay, do the ini:

```
pluginPaths.Xyz_Resource='Xyz/Resource/'
```

The same. No help. I believed that the basepaths of the plugin paths would include the PHP "include" paths. Am I mistaken in that? Any other ideas? I'll happily write up what finally works for me to help some other poor soul in this circumstance. Something to do with Name Spaces, maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plugin classes are resolved using the plugin loader, which works slightly differently to the autoloader; so just requiring the class in doesn't help you here. Instead, add this to your application.ini:

```
pluginPaths.Application_Resource = "Application/Resource"
```

you should then be able to use the class as normal. Since your path above will be checked before the default Zend one, you can also name your class 'Log' and still extend the Logger resource to override the standard functionality.

Comment: +1.  Also just a note to the question author, you shouldn't name your resource Zend_* because that is reserved for classes that are actually part of the framework.  From the [naming conventions](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.naming-conventions.html) page: Note: *Important*: Code that must be deployed alongside Zend Framework libraries but is not part of the standard or extras libraries (e.g. application code or libraries that are not distributed by Zend) must never start with "Zend_" or "ZendX_".